# Should I add the names or skip them altogether?

Tags: writing-style, presentation

I am making a presentation on the topic **Coral Reefs and their Conservation**. I have included much of the information with reference to National Geographic channel's blog reports and United Foundations' reports. I have referred four websites, all of which were inter-related in some way (apart from the topic, of  course). They included the research work of a certain someone named Dr. Emma Camp and Associate Professor  David Sugget. These two were the leaders/mentors of the program which included many other PhD students and a few MSc students as well.

I have mentioned about two recent significant programs carried out for the recovery of coral reefs, **Coral Nurture Program** and **Future Reefs Program.** Both of the two programs have these two people in common along with a few others. So I was thinking of including a brief summary of both of them. But then I thought that wouldn't be just, because there were many other students and researchers as well.

Hence my question, should I include their summaries in my presentations **or** should I mention everyone's name as per this [site](https://www.uts.edu.au/research-and-teaching/our-research/climate-change-cluster/research-programs/future-reefs) **or** should I avoid this notion altogether?

Comment: It is also relevant for who /  where the presentation is meant. In a close group meeting you have several ways to refer to the material you have used. That is not possible more if the presentation is formal and for extended audiences.

Comment: @Alchimista It is to be presented in front of the class (via video conferencing platforms).

Comment: So credit are always important but this looks like homework presented to peers. Give reference to the source and forget formalities.

Answer (score 1):

For many different reasons, you should always give credit/citation to those who have earned it. One type of reason is that your work depends on their work. Another type of reason is to recognize their prior work, even if your work does not necessarily depend on it. Another reason is to give indications to your audience about sources for further information...

EDIT: for situations where some people are doing critical work (such as diving...) but maybe not literally writing, although traditional "citation" does not quite work, I'd still want to make a point of saying something like "the work of <divers, by name> was critical to this study".

Comment: I have included links in the reference section to all five websites ( four + one where I had taken some pictures from). However, citation would mean referring or giving credit to the work of some author or writer. I can include the name of the person who wrote the blog post, but that doesn't necessarily appraise the work of those researchers who are working underwater. What should I do in such case?